# Spring Boot Google Sheet Integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-sheets, devops

In my Spring Boot application, there is a Google Sheets integration. To write data to a Google Sheet, we need to authorize the application using the account that has been added as a test user in the Google Console OAuth consent screen. The link to authorize the application is printed on the terminal. This process works fine in my local environment. I have a Docker container for this setup. However, on the production server, although the URL is printed on the terminal, upon authorization, the browser shows an error indicating that the server took too long to respond.[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0WZr.png)

What might be the issue causing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.